# keyset does not exist in accessing a x509certificate2 in c#

Tags: c#, cryptography

when I try to use the x509Certificate2 object for the first time after installing it thorugh its pfx then it can sign the data, but from the very second time it can't and show an error that keyset does not exist on the line...

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
```

in the debug it is shown also that

```
A first chance exception of type 
'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

can not figure out the problem here...

Comment: maybe, post some more information from the Exception. The InnerException if any...

Answer (score 3):

I have got the solution...

after running successfully for the first time, the private key becomes inaccessible, thus the problem was created.

solution is adding a single line of code:

```
csp.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
```

it ensures the key is accessible.

Comment: After it was broken what did you do to get it to work again, I too have the same problem the very first time it ran it worked and then after that it failed, even when I restart the computer it fails

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if the Windows user trying to access the private key doesn't have permissions to do so. To fix open MMC and add the Certificates snap-in, find the certificate, right click All Tasks -> Manage Private Key and give that specific user permission to read the private key.